# Not able to send mail by php-script

Tags: php, linux, email

I found a php-script on internet:

```
<?php
$to = "*******@yahoo.com";
$subject = "Test mail";
$message = "Hello! This is a simple email message.";
$from = "****@*****.nu";
$headers = "From:" . $from;
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
echo "Mail Sent.";
?>
```

and it work perfectly if I use it from my web-hotel. But i need it to by run on my home-server and I just simply not receiving anything. I tried to run it with `php -f phpTest`, and through both local ip (10.0.0.2) and by using a global hostname. I just get "Mail send" without getting the mail.

It is a ubuntu-server I am running at and it uses apache2. Like I said, it is no wrong in script because it worked on web-hotel. It should be something with my local settings, but I can't figure out what.

All help would be appreciated!

\\demon

Comment: do you have a mail dæmon set up? If not, best to ask about that on superuser.

Comment: You should check your mail logs/settings on your server.

Comment: Check your destination spam folder? Do you sign your messages?

Answer (score 1):

The PHP `mail` function uses a local MTA (Mail Transport Agent), that is a mail deamon running on the same machine as your PHP interpreter and your Apache web server.

So you must install and configure one on your Ubuntu setup. `sendmail` is the classic one, but `exim` is said to be easily configurable, and can use your current SMTP server as a smarthost relay, which works well for a home server.

```
sudo apt-get install exim4-daemon-light
sudo dpkg-reconfigure exim4-config
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of relying on the builtin `mail` function which needs a working MTA, you could use a library like [Swiftmailer](http://swiftmailer.org/) to send the mail [through an existing SMTP server](http://swiftmailer.org/docs/sending.html) (e.g. your regular mail address). That way you have the additional bonus of less spam filtering (because spam filters are sometimes very suspicious of mails that were sent from home servers).

Comment: This is absolutely the best Option for you. I once tried to set up my own Mail SMTP Server at Home but with a dynamic IP you could totally forget it. Even with a fixed IP you still get filtered out by most Mail Servers